# Is there a way to click a list of multiple buttons, one by one, in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, repeat

I am a student working on a scraping project with selenium on python. I am trying to scrape data from multiple profiles, that are all formatted the same. There is a directory website with buttons that lead to all of the profiles, but the problem that I am having is being able to click every button one at a time because they are all formatted the same. My goal is to be able to open the 1st link in a new tab, scrape the data from that profile, then close the first profile's tab and move on too the second. I hope to make this process repeatable. Here is what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="MY PATH TO MY CHROME DRIVER")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("http://directory.bcsp.org")

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('View Profile')
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions to my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"body" for to go down on the page

"profile_count" for get link

".get_attribute('href')" for to scrape the link from the "View Profile" button

"temp" the information in the old window does not switch to the new window so we need temp

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://directory.bcsp.org/")
count = int(input("Count : "))

body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body") #
profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

while len(profile_count) < count: # Get links up to "count"
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
    sleep(1)
    profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

for link in profile_count: # Calling up links
    temp = link.get_attribute('href') # temp for 
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');") # open new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) # focus new tab
    driver.get(temp)
    #   you can do
    #   what you want
    #   to do here
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.close()
```

Comment: Sorry for not being able to explain the code too much, you can ask if there is a part you are stuck on